# Delete and Update from google app engine datastore

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, quercus

I use Quercus to run php on google app engine and use GAE LowLevel Api to connect datastore.
I need sample php code to CRUD ( Create, Read, Update, Delete ) in datastore.
I have Create and Read sample php code.

Create entry to datastore

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;

$entity = new Entity("test"); 
$entity->setProperty('field1','value1');
$entity->setProperty('field2','value2');
$dataService = DatastoreServiceFactory::getDatastoreService();
$dataService->put($entity);
?>
```

Query to datastore

```
<?php
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query;
import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory;

$q = new Query('test');
//http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query.html
$q->addFilter('field1','EQUAL' ,'value1');
$dataService = DatastoreServiceFactory::getDatastoreService();
$prepared = $dataService->prepare($q);
foreach($prepared->asIterable() as $i) {
echo $field1 = $i->getProperty('field1');
echo $field2 = $i->getProperty('field2');
}
?>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to **Delete** and **Update** entries in datastore with php?

Answer (score 1):

the `DatastoreService.put()` call works for both create and update. the app engine datastore doesn't differentiate between them at the API level. so, the code in your first example should work for update too. just use an existing entity that you got from a `get()` or query.

as for delete, i haven't tried this, but based on your example code, both `$dataService->delete($key)` and `$dataService->delete($entity->key())` should work, depending on whether you have a key or an entity.